# Struts 1 and connection-pooling

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling, struts-1

I've succeeded in using connection-pooling in my web app (which doesn't use the Struts framework). Now I need to integrate a part written by another developer (part that uses the Struts 1 framework). The problem is that I don't succeed in using the pool with Struts 1.

Should it possible?

In my Tomcat context.xml, I have:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
          username="auser" password="apwd" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" 
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" />
```

The other developer is using connections from servlet execute like:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "auser", "apwd");
```

Comment: The other part should use the same code as you are using to get a connection from the pool. The code from the developer doesn't use a pool, and can't be left as is if a pool must be used. You need to fix the other developer's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code something like this in servlet

```
// Obtain our environment naming context
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

// Look up our data source
DataSource ds = (DataSource)
  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MyDB");

// Allocate and use a connection from the pool
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
... use this connection to access the database ...
conn.close();
```

For more details refer

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/database-connection-pooling-tomcat-eclipse-db/